# El filtrado no trabajan en la rejilla telerik mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Este es mi código que muestra la red cuando se carga la página.

Cuando entro en el texto para filtrar , se dice que no hay registros que mostrar.

```
@model IEnumerable<SAReds.UI.Web.Models.DepartmentModel>

 @(Html.Telerik().Grid<SAReds.UI.Web.Models.DepartmentModel>(Model)
     .Name("Grid")
         .DataKeys(keys =>
         {
             keys.Add(o => o.Id);
         })
     .Columns(columns =>
     {
         columns.Bound(o => o.CompanyName).Title("Company Name").Width(150);
         columns.Bound(o => o.Name).Title("Department Name").Width(150);
         columns.Bound(o => o.Active).Width(100).Title("Active");
         columns.Template(o => Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditDepartment", new { o.Id })).Width(35)
         .ClientTemplate("<a href=\" " + Url.Action("EditDepartment", "Task") + "/<#= Id#>\">Edit</a>")
         .Title("Edit");
     })
        .DataBinding(dataBinding =>
        {
            dataBinding.Server().Select("CompanyDepartment", "Task", new
            {
                ajax =
                ViewData["ajax"]
            });
            dataBinding.Ajax().Select("_CompanyDepartment",
                "Task").Enabled((bool)ViewData["ajax"]);
        })
       .Scrollable(scrolling => scrolling.Enabled((bool)ViewData["scrolling"]))
       .Sortable(sorting => sorting.Enabled((bool)ViewData["sorting"]))
       .Pageable(paging => paging.Enabled((bool)ViewData["paging"]))
       .Filterable(filtering => filtering.Enabled((bool)ViewData["filtering"]))
       .Groupable(grouping => grouping.Enabled((bool)ViewData["grouping"]))
       .Footer((bool)ViewData["showFooter"]) )
```

código del controlador

```
public ActionResult CompanyDepartment(bool? ajax, bool? scrolling, bool? paging, bool? filtering, bool? sorting,bool? grouping, bool? showFooter)
{
        ViewData["ajax"] = ajax ?? true;
        ViewData["scrolling"] = scrolling ?? true;
        ViewData["paging"] = paging ?? true;
        ViewData["filtering"] = filtering ?? true;
        ViewData["grouping"] = grouping ?? true;
        ViewData["sorting"] = sorting ?? true;
        ViewData["showFooter"] = showFooter ?? true;


        IDataOperations ops = DataSession.GetDataOperations(null);
        List<Department> Depts = new List<Department>();
        List<Employee> employeeList = new List<Employee>();
        ops.Load(Depts).Select("*").From("Department");
        ops.Commit();
        //Employee employee = new Employee();
        Company company = new Company();
        ops.Load(employeeList);
        ops.Commit();

        List<DepartmentModel> deptModel = new List<DepartmentModel>();
        foreach(Department dp in Depts)
        {
            ops.Load(company).FilterColumns("Id").Values(new { Id = dp.CompanyId });
            ops.Commit();

            deptModel.Add(new DepartmentModel()
            {
                Id = dp.Id,
                CompanyId = dp.CompanyId,
                Active = dp.Active,
                Name = dp.Name,
                CompanyName = company.Name
            });
        }

        return View(deptModel);
    }

    [GridAction]
    public ActionResult _CompanyDepartment()
    {

        IDataOperations ops = DataSession.GetDataOperations(null);
        List<Department> Depts = new List<Department>();
        ops.Load(Depts).Select("*").From("Department");

        List<DepartmentModel> deptModel = new List<DepartmentModel>();
        foreach (Department dp in Depts)
        {
            deptModel.Add(new DepartmentModel()
            {
                Id = dp.Id,
                CompanyId = dp.CompanyId,
                Active = dp.Active,
                Name = dp.Name
            });
        }

        return View(new GridModel<<SAReds.UI.Web.Models.DepartmentModel>>
        {
            Data = deptModel
        });
    }
```

Por favor ayuda.Gracias.

Comment: si se trata de un filtro lo que ingresa el usuario como recibes el valor en _CompanyDepartment ? si pones un breakpoint puedes evaluar que valor ingresa.

Comment: Si usas el developer tools del browser, al cual accedes con F12, usando la solapa network deberias poder evaluar si se realiza el request ajax al server para aplicar el filtro, alli podrias ver que datos se envian y la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

No termino de entender bien la lógica de por qué hay veces que utilizas [server binding](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-data-binding-server-binding.html) y otras [ajax binding](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-data-binding-ajax-binding.html) (no sé exactamente la versión de Telerik que estás utilizando, pero supongo que esa documentación es la que a se apega medianamente a tu versión dado lo que veo en tu código)

Yo intentaría probar si no es algo relacionado al binding de datos que no sabe cuál utilizar cuando realiza el filtro. Probaría usando solo server binding luego solo ajax binding y en caso de que las dos formas funcione, en ese caso intentaría con la lógica de enable/disable de estos métodos.

Se que no responde exactamente tu pregunta pero espero que ayude.

Saludos